# How to apply jquery only to the element selected with if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, each

I am trying to select a certain element on a page. All the elements have the same class same everything, with the only exception that the background image is different on some of them.

What I need to do is to ONLY apply the jquery code to only the element chosen via the if statement.

Please note I cannot edit the HTML, I need to use jquery for this.

Here is my code:

```
$('.repeated-element').each( function(){
   if ( $(this).css('background-image').indexOf('mystringzzz') ) {
    //do something
      alert("works");
      $(this).closest('div.someclass').addClass('aclassilike');
    //stop loop
      return false;
   }
});
```

I have selected the element just fine and jquery is running. I know this because I get the alert popup which shows that part (`if ( $(this).css('background-image').indexOf('mystringzzz') ) {`) works.

However, the problem is that I can only get it to apply to either the first element (which is not the one that is selected) or to all of the elements.

If I use:

```
$(this).closest('div.someclass').addClass('aclassilike');
```

the result is it applies to only the very first recurrence on the page, NOT the selected one.

Alternatively if I use:

```
$('.repeated-element').closest('div.someclass').addClass('aclassilike');
```

Then the result is it applies every recurrence on the page, **not only** the selected ones. It is supposed to be only the selected one.

How can I ONLY apply the jquery code to only the element chosen via the if statement?

For example,

> a) inside the `.repeated-element`,
>   b) ONLY which contains a `background-image` css in the external stylesheet which has part of the image name as `mystringzzz`,
>   c) then apply the new jquery (in this example adding another class).
>   d) But do not apply it to elements which do not contain the `mystringzzz` string in `background-image`.

Comment: I think you're intention is to apply only to the selected element with that background, right ?

Comment: @Burimi yep that is correct, that is my intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the problem was that you weren't checking if the index did not equate to `-1` in your [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) call. If you were to write this in the original format of your question it would look like this:

```
$('.repeated-element').each(function() {
   if ($(this).css('background-image').indexOf('mystringzzz') !== -1) {
     //do something
      alert("works");
      $(this).closest('div.someclass').addClass('aclassilike');
      //stop loop
      return false;
   }
});
```

With all that being said jQuery's methods have certain use-cases depending on the scenario. I'd highly recommend just using [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) in this case:

```
$('.repeated-element').filter(function() {
  return $(this).css('background-image').indexOf('mystringzzz') !== -1;
}).closest('div.someclass').addClass('aclassilike');
```

Comment: Thanks for updating that I see you fixed it. Will try.

Comment: Filter will narrow the collection down to whatever you specify in the callback.

Comment: Great to hear! Glad I was able to help out.

Comment: I would like to see how I could use in my `IF` statement and fix it to make it work that way, since this did not solve my original problem for learning's sake even though it solved my specific problem. I chose as best anyway but would like to see a specific solution using `if` statement. For example, as it is, this only works to concatenate some jquery like `.addClass`. `It does not work if you want to run some jquery code like an alert for example`.

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much, I now see the error of my code, I needed `!== -1`. I did not realize the importance of that. Thanks again!

Comment: Just a note I just am taking a javascript course and now I understand why `-1` matters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DOM directly from any event handler, if you're interested only on selected element.

```
$('.repeated-element').click(function(){
  if ( $(this).css('background-image').indexOf('mystringzzz') ) {
    //do something
      alert("works");
      $(this).closest('div.someclass').addClass('aclassilike');
    //stop loop
      return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: @user7783780 No it doesn't look like. In your answer you don't have any event handler. Please fix your answer and make it clear what is your problem.

Comment: all you did was change `each` to `click`. This is not useful. I need it to run at page load not on click. Element will never be clicked on. There is no interaction with the element.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you also need to remove the `url` from the `background-image` property

```js
$('.repeated-element').each(function() {
  // removing url and only getting the image 
  var getURL = $(this).css('background-image').replace('url(', '').replace(')', '').replace(/\"/gi, "");
  if (getURL.indexOf('mystringzzz') !== -1) {
    $(this).closest('div.someclass').addClass('aclassilike');
  }

});
```

```css
.repeated-element {
  color: red
}

.aclassilike {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='someclass'>
  <div style='background-image:url("mystringzzz")' class='repeated-element'>1</div>
</div>

<div class='someclass'>
  <div class='repeated-element'>1</div>
</div>
<div class='someclass'>
  <div class='repeated-element'>1</div>
</div>
<div class='someclass'>
  <div style='background-image:url("mystringzzz")' class='repeated-element'>1</div>
</div>
```